# Response code 302 on access to correct URL with Apache Camel

Tags: java, web-services, post, apache-camel, http-status-code-302

I'm using Apache Camel to access to web service and got strange problem with invoking .NET web service.

That's the POST request sent by Camel:

```
ID: 1
Address: http://<domainName>/<pathToService>.asmx
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], breadcrumbId=[ID-someId-1449849054155-0-1], SOAPAction=["http://<someNamespace>/<SoapActionName>"]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>/soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

That's the response:

```
ID: 1
Response-Code: 302
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[private], Content-Length=[223], content-type=[text/html; charset=utf-8], Location=[/<somePath>/CustomError.htm?aspxerrorpath=/<pathToService>.asmx], Persistent-Auth=[true], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], X-UA-Compatible=[IE=7]}
Payload: <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head></html>
```

When I request "http://*domainName*/*pathToService*" in browser I see the correct answer.

When I request "http://*domainName*/*pathToService*.asmx?wsdl" I'm getting the wsdl file.

If I change *SoapActionName* to incorrect value I'm getting

```
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find the BindingOperationInfo with operation name ..."
```

it's correct behavior too, of course.

I presume that I need to tune Camel to make it able to work with .NET web service.

But how?

Camel configuration (all in Spring DSL):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
   xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
   xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

<bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>
<bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>

<bean id="exceptionHandler" class="...ExceptionHandler"/>

<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="wsEndpoint"
                 address="${ws.host}/service.asmx"
                 serviceClass="pathToServiceClass"
                 loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
                 endpointName="endpointName">
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="POJO"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>

<http:conduit name="{serviceClass}endpointName.http-conduit">
    <http:authorization>
        <sec:UserName>domain\username</sec:UserName>
        <sec:Password>password</sec:Password>
        <sec:AuthorizationType>NTLM</sec:AuthorizationType>
    </http:authorization>
</http:conduit>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route id="mainRoute">
        <from uri="file://inbox"/>
        <setHeader headerName="operationName">
            <constant>AcquireTicket</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="cxf:bean:wsEndpoint" pattern="InOut"/>
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <process ref="exceptionHandler"/>
        </onException>
        <to uri="log:mylog?Level=INFO"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I invoke Camel with JUnit:

```
    @Test
public void testWebservice() throws Exception {
    ... 
   forming request
   ...

    context.getRouteDefinition("mainRoute")
            .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    replaceFromWith("direct:in");
                }
            });
    context.start();


    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    template.sendBody("direct:in",request);
}
```

I tried to use request web service without Camel, with Apache HttpClient:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.NTLM,new JCIFSNTLMSchemeFactory());
    httpClient.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.SPNEGO,new JCIFSNTLMSchemeFactory());
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    NTCredentials ntCredentials = new NTCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD,
            InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), DOMAIN);
    HttpHost target = new HttpHost(HOST,80,"http");
    credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort(),
            AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "NTLM"), ntCredentials);
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, ntCredentials);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

    post.addHeader("SOAPAction", SOAP_ACTION);
    post.addHeader("Content-Type",CONTENT_TYPE);
    post.addHeader("Accept-Encoding",ACCEPT_ENCODING);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = new StringEntity(getShortText());
    post.setEntity(httpEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

There is the last (3 of 3 NTLM requests) POST request created by Camel:

```
    POST /<pathToService>.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
    Accept: */*
    SOAPAction:<someNamespace>/<SoapActionName>
    User-Agent: Apache CXF 3.1.4
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Pragma: no-cache
    Host: localhost:8013
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 269
    Authorization: NTLM <Token>
```

There is the last (3 of 3 NTLM requests) POST request created with the code above by Apache HttpClient:

```
    POST /<pathToService>.asmx HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    SOAPAction:<someNamespace>/<SoapActionName>
    User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

    Host: localhost:8013
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Length: 269
    Authorization: NTLM <Token>
```

Both requests looks equals to me, but IIS response for the Camel request is HTTP 302 and IIS response for the Apache HttpCLient is HTTP 200.

Host is localhost:8013 because I use listener to analyze HTTP traffic, that listener forward all request to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Because your browser can follow 302 redirection from the location header.

The response you get is a HTTP 302 which is redirection based on the location header. So you need to tell Camel to follow 302 and get the URI from the location header.

Comment: Thank you for response. The problem is that I'm using the correct location.

Comment: I added new information in my question, please look at it.

Comment: Question updated, I added Camel code and information about how I invoke it.

Comment: I've found the reason, Camel sends requests with wrong user's credential - which is user that runs Camel, and not credentials that specified in Camel configuration. And IIS sends HTTP 302 response if user didnt have rights to call the web service. Now the task is to make Camel to use correct user in request sending.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

1. Add `<http:client/>` element to `<http:conduit/>`. My example:

   ```
   <http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
       <http:client
           AllowChunking="false"
           MaxRetransmits="11"
           Connection="Keep-Alive"
           ReceiveTimeout="30000"
           CacheControl="No-Cache"
       />
       <http:authorization>
           <sec:UserName>domain\username</sec:UserName>
           <sec:Password>password</sec:Password>
           <sec:AuthorizationType>NTLM</sec:AuthorizationType>
       </http:authorization>
   </http:conduit>
   ```
2. Force JRE to use Camel provided properties. My example:

2.1 Create class that changes the NTLM authorization option in constructor:

```
    public class NTLMCallbackHelper {

public NTLMCallbackHelper() {
    NTLMAuthenticationCallback.setNTLMAuthenticationCallback(
            new NTLMAuthenticationCallback () {
                @Override
                public boolean isTrustedSite(URL url) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    );
}
```

2.2 Add bean to application context before any CXF beans:

```
<bean id = "NTLMCallbackHelper" class="my.package.NTLMCallbackHelper"/>
```

With this solution I got HTTP 200 response code from IIS.